# Flatten list of dictionaries into dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following data which contain lists of dictionaries

```
data= [
 {'Time': 18057610.0,
  'Flux': [{'V0': -1.4209e-15},
   {'V1': 2.7353e-16},
   {'V2': 1.1935e-15},
   {'V3': 1.1624},
   {'V4': -6.1692e-15},
   {'V5': 3.2218e-15}]},
 {'Time': 18057620.4,
  'Flux': [{'V0': 2.4377e-16},
   {'V1': -6.2809e-15},
   {'V2': 1.6456e-15},
   {'V3': 1.1651},
   {'V4': 1.7147e-15},
   {'V5': 9.8872e-16}]},
 {'Time': 18057631.1,
  'Flux': [{'V0': 4.1124e-15},
   {'V1': 1.5598e-15},
   {'V2': -2.325e-16},
   {'V3': 1.1638},
   {'V4': -3.9983e-15},
   {'V5': 4.459e-16}]}]
```

I want to get something like this:

`preferred_df`:

```
                     V0            V1  ...            V4            V5
Time                                    ...                            
18057610.0 -1.420900e-15  2.735300e-16  ... -6.169200e-15  3.221800e-15
18057620.4  2.437700e-16 -6.280900e-15  ...  1.714700e-15  9.887200e-16
18057631.1  4.112400e-15  1.559800e-15  ... -3.998300e-15  4.459000e-16
```

I came up with the following code which serves the purpose:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).explode('Flux').reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Flux').values.tolist())).groupby('Time').sum()
```

However, I don't want to use `groupby` and `sum()`. What are the other ways (dictionary comprehension?) to flatten the `"Flux"` column without getting the NaN values while flattening the dictionaries and get the `preferred_df`? I tried `json_normalize()` but got same NaNs and needed to use `groupby()` and `sum()`.

**Based on accepeted answer**:

*Here is the extended `for loop` version of the accepted answer from **Andrej Kesely**'s dictionary comprehension inside a list comprehension:*

```
list=[]
index=[]   
for d in data:
    dict={}
    idx=d['Time']
    for d2 in d['Flux']:        
        for k, v in d2.items():
            dict[k]=v
    list.append(dict) 
    index.append(idx)  
     
df=pd.DataFrame(list,index )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [{k: v for d2 in d["Flux"] for k, v in d2.items()} for d in data],
    index=[d["Time"] for d in data],
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                      V0            V1            V2      V3            V4            V5
18057610.0 -1.420900e-15  2.735300e-16  1.193500e-15  1.1624 -6.169200e-15  3.221800e-15
18057620.4  2.437700e-16 -6.280900e-15  1.645600e-15  1.1651  1.714700e-15  9.887200e-16
18057631.1  4.112400e-15  1.559800e-15 -2.325000e-16  1.1638 -3.998300e-15  4.459000e-16
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the built-in `collections.ChainMap` method in a list comprehension:

```
from collections import ChainMap
out = pd.DataFrame([d | ChainMap(*d.pop('Flux')) for d in data])
```

Output:

```
         Time            V0            V1            V2      V3            V4            V5
0  18057610.0 -1.420900e-15  2.735300e-16  1.193500e-15  1.1624 -6.169200e-15  3.221800e-15
1  18057620.4  2.437700e-16 -6.280900e-15  1.645600e-15  1.1651  1.714700e-15  9.887200e-16
2  18057631.1  4.112400e-15  1.559800e-15 -2.325000e-16  1.1638 -3.998300e-15  4.459000e-16
```

Answer (score 1):

one option is `pd.json_normalize` followed by a groupby (it won't be as efficient as the previous options where the wrangling is done within Python):

```py
( pd
.json_normalize(data, 'Flux', ['Time'])
.groupby('Time', as_index = False)
.min()
)

         Time            V0            V1            V2      V3            V4            V5
0  18057610.0 -1.420900e-15  2.735300e-16  1.193500e-15  1.1624 -6.169200e-15  3.221800e-15
1  18057620.4  2.437700e-16 -6.280900e-15  1.645600e-15  1.1651  1.714700e-15  9.887200e-16
2  18057631.1  4.112400e-15  1.559800e-15 -2.325000e-16  1.1638 -3.998300e-15  4.459000e-1
```